# How to include multiple emscripten libraries with multiple preloaded MEMFS filesystems

Tags: emscripten

I have to include multiple libraries for a project - I've already succeeded in including multiple emscripten libraries but I cannot seem to access the preloaded MEMFS filesystem in the 2nd one.

In the second library I use the

```
--embed-file
```

parameter in the linker to embed a whole directory with the JS file output but when I access the files in the web console via

```
FS.stat()
```

I cannot access any file that was embedded.

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I initially had a similar behaviour. It turned out to be the "file" part of it that every browser would treat differently.

If your are running your page from a server, then this is not the case.

Otherwise have a look at : https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#tutorial-files

> Unfortunately Chrome and Internet Explorer do not support file:// XHR requests, and can’t directly load the local file in which preloaded data is stored. For these browsers you’ll need to serve the files using a webserver. The easiest way to do this is to use the python SimpleHTTPServer (in the current directory do python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 and then open http://localhost:8080/hello.html).